# Failing to set a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I use WSL2, and need an environment variable called `DISPLAY` to communicate with XServer which is running on my host (windows) IP.
I am trying to set this environment each time my shell starts using my `.bashrc`. It has to update each time because my IP is dynamically assigned.

Here is the section of the code in the `.bashrc` responsible for setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

```
alias windowsip="ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2 | head -1 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'"
WINDOWSIP="$(windowsip)"
ENDING=":0.0"

export DISPLAY="$WINDOWSIP$ENDING"
```

Although the `.bashrc` runs quietly, there are a number of things that indicate that the environment variable was not set as desired.

Firstly,

```
bensmus@BENSMUSPC:~$ $DISPLAY
:0.0: command not found
bensmus@BENSMUSPC:~$
```

This is strange because my `windowsip` command works fine, and gives output without any leading spaces.

```
bensmus@BENSMUSPC:~$ windowsip
123.123.1.23
bensmus@BENSMUSPC:~$
```

(Note: My ip is not 123.123.1.23, I just feel weird about sharing my IP)

Even more strangely, when I do

```
bensmus@BENSMUSPC:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0123.1.23
```

What the heck is going on?

I really want it to just be

```
bensmus@BENSMUSPC:~$ echo $DISPLAY
123.123.1.23:0.0
```

Comment: Unrelated: Don't give the command `$DISPLAY`. Do `echo $DISPLAY` to see what its value is. About the IP: Does it start with 192.168.? :)

Comment: `What the heck is going on?` Your file has dos line endings. Also, what's the point? There is localhost - 127.0.0.1 - to connect with... local host. And `:0.0` without any ip will connect to localhost... so why do you set it at all?

Comment: I don't understand how localhost is applicable here. I need to connect to the IP of my Windows machine that is running WSL 2.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it does!

Comment: @BenjaminSmus The 192.168.x.x address is your LAN IP address. Your WAN IP address (that can be used to try to connect to your network) is something completely different. My LAN IP is 192.168.1.140 for example.

Comment: @KamilCuk Just based on experimentation, :0.0 is necessary in my case. Currently what I do to use XServer is run `export DISPLAY=192.168.1.23:0.0`, and if I don't include :0.0, it doesn't work

Comment: Btw, what if you do: WINDOWSIP="$(ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2 | head -1 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//') instead? Same problem? Hmm, is `ipconfig.exe` even available? I don't have that in my WSL2 bash shell.

Comment: Exactly the same thing @TedLyngmo, yes ipconfig.exe works!

Comment: To see exactly what's in that variable: `printf '%s' "$DISPLAY" | od -c` or `printf '%q\n' "$DISPLAY"`

Comment: A little late but I realized you can just pipe the output from `ipconfig.exe` thru `dos2unix`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a char `0d` character at the end of the data returned by the `windowsip` alias (probably because of the output encoding of ipconfig.exe):

```
myprompt~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0168.1.7

myprompt~$ echo $DISPLAY | xxd
00000000: 3139 322e 3136 382e 312e 370d 3a30 2e30  192.168.1.7.:0.0
00000010: 0a
```

Since `0d` is the carriage return, I guess the weird result of printing `$DISPLAY` is caused by the print logic returning to the beginning of the line when it encounters `0d`. But maybe that was obvious to everyone besides me...

### Better Answer:

Since this is just a windows/unix newline issue, running `ipconfig.exe` through `dos2unix` seems to fix the problem:

```
alias windowsip="ipconfig.exe | dos2unix | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2 | head -1 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'"
```

Leading to:

```
myprompt:~$ echo $DISPLAY
192.168.1.7:0.0
myprompt~$ echo $DISPLAY | xxd
00000000: 3139 322e 3136 382e 312e 373a 302e 300a  192.168.1.7:0.0.
```

### Previous Answer:

I'm not sure why there is an `0d` in the middle and then a `0d` at the end, but if you remove both with sed, it seems to work for me:

```
alias windowsip="ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2 | head -1 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//;s/[\n\r]//g;'"
```

This leads to:

```
myprompt~$ echo $DISPLAY
192.168.1.7:0.0
myprompt~$ echo $DISPLAY | xxd
00000000: 3139 322e 3136 382e 312e 373a 302e 300a  192.168.1.7:0.0.
```

I'm not sure why it has a `0a` at the end, but that seems to be the case if you just set it to a string:

```
myprompt~$ DISPLAY="192.168.1.7:0.0"
myprompt~$ echo $DISPLAY | xxd
00000000: 3139 322e 3136 382e 312e 373a 302e 300a  192.168.1.7:0.0.
```

Comment: It's because the .bashrc file itself contains CRNL line endings, so the variable assignment is actually seen as `WINDOWSIP="$(windowsip)"\r` and `ENDING=":0.0"\r` -- sed is not the answer, removing the carriage returns from the dotfile is.

Comment: An alternative using `awk`: `ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | head -1 | dos2unix | awk '{ print $NF }'`